# How do I find out why the phone is executing my Toast?

Tags: android

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
switch(v.getId()) {
  ...
    case R.id.folder:
        Intent openFolder=new Intent(this,Folder.class);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please wait...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(openFolder);
        break;
    ...
 }
}
```

folder is the id of a textview. When the textview is clicked, Folder activity should be opened. But it takes 9 secs for the activity to open, so I decided to put a toast to let the user know the app is opening the activity. But somehow, this Toast isn't popping up why?

Can I use the debugger to find out why?

Comment: Put a break point at the toast, see if the debugger reaches that point.

Comment: Try to make asynchronous the heavy work in Folder activity and show the Toast in  it.

Comment: @TDG, the debugger does reach that point. The weird thing is sometime the Toast pops. Other times, it doesn't.